# PHP imagejpeg not displaying image on Browser

Tags: php, image, jpeg

I am using imagejpg() to display an image on the browser and place text over the image.

I have used this before and it has worked. Now I switched domain hosts and perhaps the PHP version is different as the image is now not displaying.

It displays a small square in the middle of the screen, like a broken link, but the image is definitely there.

Could someone please assist with this?

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Create Image From Existing File
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images1/new_image.jpg');

// Allocate A Color For The Text
$red = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 0, 0);
$green = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 0, 255, 0);

// Set Path to Font File
$font_path = 'canadian.ttf';

$text1 = "hello";
$text2 = "there";
$text3 = "world";

//Floor 17
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 12, 0, 272, 17, $green, $font_path, $text1);
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 12, 0, 200, 38, $green, $font_path, $text2);
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 12, 0, 480, 17, $green, $font_path, $text3);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
```

Thank you in advance.

Rob

Comment: My suggestion is to remove the first line: `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");` Have a look at what appears on the page, 9/10 times it'll be a PHP error, which you couldn't see because the page was being rendered as an image.

Comment: Tried that. No Error, just a page full of text symbols eg. ÿØÿàJFIFÿþ>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ÿÛC    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC  2!!2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. Answer below

I moved the header down and it sorted out the problem.

```
// Create Image From Existing File
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images1/new_image.jpg');

// Allocate A Color For The Text
$red = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 0, 0);
$green = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 0, 255, 0);

// Set Path to Font File
$font_path = 'canadian.ttf';

$text1 = "hello";
$text2 = "there";
$text3 = "world";

//Floor 17
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 12, 0, 272, 17, $green, $font_path, $text1);
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 12, 0, 200, 38, $green, $font_path, $text2);
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 12, 0, 480, 17, $green, $font_path, $text3);

  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
```

Comment: Hmm, never seen this error before... I don't see why this would affect anything though. Is there any other code on this page, or is the page dedicated to displaying the image?

Comment: Purely dedicated to display this page. I cant see why either, but it now works. Strange things happen I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, found out that if there is a blank space before the header, the image doesn't work. 
I was able to save the image on the server but not to get the browser to display it. 
Removing every blank space did the trick for me. 
I think it's the same reason why your script didn't work with the header at the beginning.